# List only the row keys in hbase after a specific timestamp from shell

Tags: hadoop, hbase

How can I list only the row keys in hbase(not values or timestamp) after a specific timestamp from shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamp is bind to columns and not to row. So if you filter by timestamp you will only return some columns of the row.

If you have a table t1 :

```
ROW             COLUMN+CELL
ID1             column=d:actif, timestamp=25, value=false
ID1             column=d:name, timestamp=22, value="Sudipto"
ID1             column=m:lastMaj, timestamp=25, value=25
ID2             column=d:actif, timestamp=24, value=false
ID2             column=m:lastMaj, timestamp=24, value=24
```

You can filter timestamp with :

```
scan 't1', { TIMERANGE => [0, 25] }
```

But you will only return :

```
ROW             COLUMN+CELL
ID1             column=d:actif, timestamp=26, value=false
ID1             column=m:lastMaj, timestamp=26, value=26
ID2             column=d:actif, timestamp=24, value=false
ID2             column=m:lastMaj, timestamp=24, value=24
```

So you lose the column :

```
ROW             COLUMN+CELL
ID1             column=d:name, timestamp=22, value="Sudipto"
```

**However**, there is a solution if you want all the columns. You can filter by a metadata (here m:lastMaj). This lastMaj data has to be updated whenever you modify a column of your row.

- Here, when i modified "d:actif", i also modified "m:lastMaj" (they both have a timestamp of 25)
- When i want to get all the rows after a specific timestamp, i will just filter rows on "m:lastMaj timestamp".
- The command to scan by value in shell could then be:

  ```
  import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
  import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter
  import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
  import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
  scan 't', { FILTER => 
      SingleColumnValueFilter.new(
          Bytes.toBytes('m'), 
          Bytes.toBytes('lastMaj'),
          CompareFilter::CompareOp.valueOf('GREATER'), 
          Bytes.toBytes('25'))
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tremo. Can you please provide me an example of how to use the filter from hbase shell.